# C# String: why string a == b operator gives different answer than a.CompareTo(b) == 0?

Tags: c#, string, comparison

I messed with C# a little and found a code that gives very uncomfortable results:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = "string", b = "string\0";
        bool b1 = a == b;
        bool b2 = (a.CompareTo(b) > 0);
        bool b3 = (a.CompareTo(b) < 0);
        bool b4 = (a.CompareTo(b) == 0);
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", b1, b2, b3, b4);
    }
```

Output:

```
string
string
False False False True
```

Expected output (on of the):

```
string
string
True False False True
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and add your expected output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result of `CompareTo` doesn't imply equality, it relates to sort order. I'm not sure it's too surprising that the null character is ignored for sorting purposes.

Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Character sets include ignorable characters. The CompareTo(String) method does not consider such characters when it performs a culture-sensitive comparison.

Comment: If your looking for the equivalent method use a.Equals(b)

Comment: But it can be security issue or a bug who assumes that `CompareTo() == 0` gives same result as equality operator.

Answer (score 1):

You want `StringComparison.Ordinal` flag: just compare strings lexicographically:

```
...
bool b2 = (a.CompareTo(b, StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0);
bool b3 = (a.CompareTo(b, StringComparison.Ordinal) < 0);
bool b4 = (a.CompareTo(b, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a(v=vs.110).aspx) returns 0 if the string instance has the same position in the sort order as the supplied value. This is something different than comparing for equality. So I would expect the outcome as you describe.